# Flutter - Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

After I upgrade Flutter I have lots of errors when I build apk. I try to solve that problem for 3 days. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint.

Flutter doctor output:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-x64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/dev/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (4 weeks ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dev/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Developer Tools/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.62.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 Pro (mobile) • fmhamjnvqgzhn7zh • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • macOS (desktop)           • macos            • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.110

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Errors on terminal:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Font asset "Free-Solid-900.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 591768 to 1308 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 4988 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
```

```
e: /Users/dev/Development/apps12/BelApp/build/map_launcher/.transforms/f59cf9b00d955923366b85b350b36f20/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/map_launcher_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/Development/apps12/BelApp/build/motion_sensors/.transforms/d7ab2f2e5819e2dd6baef3d0d86c323c/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/motion_sensors_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/856e8c9335afd0ce87b5aaeadbf67f94/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/60cd60494296ed93df1bc3a520e60248/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0e1f631c7230191cb6538c1c9f8ed7b3/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/511cae2d88ecafae56d8631bb261540a/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fa35d6364278095c3d6d3f545fa20b5e/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/401eb592a7943f6ce10e87ad6588948a/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/186f3cf0b847de5e7dd40510ff39a719/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0122c037707e9f3822f472c08fd14f7a/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/030ee7d22b23ecb933d67f231df412e8/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/256a903a8311e3d75db7adf1ffaa35ba/transformed/jetified-annotation-experimental-1.3.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.21/43d50ab85bc7587adfe3dda3dbe579e5f8d51265/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.21/43d50ab85bc7587adfe3dda3dbe579e5f8d51265/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.21/43d50ab85bc7587adfe3dda3dbe579e5f8d51265/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users/dev/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.21/d749cd5ae25da36d06e5028785038e24f9d37976/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

I try to change ext.kotlin_version, gradle version but dont work for me.

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**After upgrading your Flutter** . *Try to run these commands to resolve the issues:-*

```
* flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get
```